# HTML/CSS Nesting issues

Tags: css, html, tags, nested

I want the "Accessibility" link to just be plain text like "Welcome to my site!" but it keeps taking the properties I set for my  tags. This is my first time building a website so if you have tips about how my code looks I am open to suggestions. Thank You!

http://jsfiddle.net/kSNmS/1/

Comment: It looks like some of your tags aren't closed... Looking at the bottom of the HTML code, the "textbox" `<div>` and the `<p>` don't have ending tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How 'bout using a class on your nav links, and targeting them that way?

http://jsfiddle.net/kSNmS/4/

Comment: Wow! I didn't expect such a quick response! I am literally cheering silently to myself, it's 3am here this has been bugging me for ages. Going to accept this is as my answer when the timer lets me (: Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to change your CSS specificity for the  `<a>` tags.   Here's an article on CSS specificity that might help you: http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html.

So, to achieve what you want, change the following

```
a
{ 

    float:left;
    font-family: 'Alike', serif;
    width:17.50em;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:green; 
    background-color:silver;
    letter-spacing:5px;
    padding:0.5em 0.9em;
    border-width: 3px 1.5px 3px 1.5px   
}
```

to something with more specificity like

```
ul a
{ 

    float:left;
    font-family: 'Alike', serif;
    width:17.50em;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:green; 
    background-color:silver;
    letter-spacing:5px;
    padding:0.5em 0.9em;
    border-width: 3px 1.5px 3px 1.5px   
}
```